# Multithreading in ios

Tags: iphone, ios

Need your help.

In my application, i want to implement a background process which keeps running continuously and downloads the updated data and stores it in document folder.

And my main thread should keep checking the document folder and display the updated data in view control.

The child thread should end once the view disappears. and start again once the view appears.

What is the best way to do it? NSThread or NSOperationQueue? What precautions are required?
I also have to access few variables of the class. So is should be thread safe.

Thanks in advance.

Regards

Comment: Tried many things. but could not achieve my goal. Can anyone please suggest me something. I want to create one thread which will run continuously in background. It will have a while(1) loop in which i will download 10-20 images repeatedly. Downloading will be done synchronously/asynchronously in thread. In async calls, the problem i face is, the success/fail callback function is not called. In sync calls, the problem i face is, i am not able to send username and password in the url request.

Answer (score 2):

If you do not need to update a progress bar or something in iOS5 there is one great API method `+ sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler:` that allows you to run async download as a block inside NSOperationQueue. If not you should look into third party libs such as ASIHTTP request or [https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking](http://AFNetworking)(probably better the last one) or  you need to build you own download manager, not a simple task

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I don't just want to download data. But also have to do other task in the thread. Secondly, it should keep running in background. Do you think sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler: is the best way of doing it?

Comment: Well, depends if you need to do something with the data that are incoming while downloading.. it's not, because it just give you the opportunity to do do something in the competition handler. Let me do an example, that file you need to download is really big. In this case you would opt for a stream or a file handler that adds data as they come, not only at the end. I guess that you should that a look at AFNetoworking, is just a "simple" wrapper around NSURLconnection method.

Answer (score 0):

there are two ways to do it..

First: You use NSOperationQueue which is a bit bulkier as it is build on GCD but does have some extra features.

Second: You use GCD (grand central dispatch) looking at requirements I would say GCD seems fine as you can easily access any thread(main or background) this would be slightly quicker.

Comment: the idea behind async is to do something in background thread so that it does not effect your main queue which is generally for UI. So this is what the purpose of these, to provide you async behavior.

Comment: Not exactly, is a misunderstanding all NSURLConnection callbacks work on the main thread, you can just put a log asking for the current thread. If don't create a run loop on a secondary thread, this thread will never receive the delegate methods. An async connection doesn't block the main, just right because is async, so it attach data at chunk, for each cycle of the run loop. Moreover as you can see from the delegation callback they don't need so much time to finish. NSOperationQueue since ioS4 run all the operations on a new thread that means if you do not create a loop everything is missing

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at `- (void)performSelectorInBackground:(SEL)aSelector withObject:(id)arg` This method creates a new thread in your application, putting your application into multithreaded mode if it was not already. In your viewDidDisappear, you can stop the task when your view disappears

From Apple Docs.  Apple encourages to investigate the alternative Mac OS X technologies for implementing concurrency. This is especially true if you are not already familiar with the design techniques needed to implement a threaded application. These alternative technologies simplify the amount of work you have to do to implement concurrent paths of execution and offer much better performance than traditional threads.
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/AboutThreads/AboutThreads.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000057i-CH6-SW2

Comment: For sake of clarity, this will work using sync connection, for async connection you will not obtain a run loop that runs until the connection finishes. Having a new thread doesn't mean that your run loop live enough.

Comment: @Andrea I am facing this issue. I am using async call in my thread. and this is creating problem. So what is the best way of using async call in thread? I tried using NSThread and GCD. In both case I am facing same problem

Comment: @Andrea Now i will be trying NSOperation.